# WFP all TextBlocks not updating

Tags: c#, textblock

So my code was working just fine.  But now, even though I can confirm the variables and strings are there through a Clipboard copy, the textblocks are not updating via TextBlock.Text.  Did I turn something off?  Every single one stopped doing it at the same time.

`private void actionPing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

```
        try
        {
            Ping myPing = new Ping();


            PingReply reply = myPing.Send(HostNameIPTyped.Text.ToString(), 500);

            if (reply != null)
            {
                string tripTime = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString();
                if (tripTime == "0")
                {
                    
                    PingStatus1.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#660000"));
                    PingStatus1.Text = "Device not found";  <---NONE OF THESE ARE UPDATING ACROSS THE ENTIRE PROGRAM
                }
                else
                {

                    PingStatus1.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#17b05c"));
                    PingStatus1.Text = "Ping Successful, " + reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms roundtrip";
                   
                    //// LET'S GET THE IP AND HOSTNAME OF WHATEVER THE HELL YOU PUT IN
                    
                    ////IPADDRESS
                    try
                    {
                        System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(HostNameIPTyped.Text.ToString()).AddressList.Where(o => o.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First();

                        ipAddress = ip.ToString();
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { }
                    


                    ////HOSTNAME
                    try
                    {
                        System.Net.IPHostEntry hostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
                        machineName = hostEntry.HostName;

                        string linkBuild = "http://" + machineName; 
                       
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }
                    PingStatus1.Text += " " + machineName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            {
                PingStatus1.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#660000"));
                PingStatus1.Text = "Device not found";
            }
        }
        
        
       
    }`
```

Comment: Your question needs a lot more detail before anyone can reasonably answer it. Are you using binding? Are you updating the bound properties? Or are you updating the textblocks some other way?

Comment: Using a very simple Click state for a button that says TextBlock.Text = "Test";   This was working but magically stopped on all textblocks.

Comment: Example...  THis is my Ping.  It was working just fine to update the textblock.  I haven't changed anything in it.  The kicker is that it still actually does ping and DOES return the IP and Hostname and all the rest, it just refuses to update the textblock. `

                        PingStatus1.Text = "Ping Successful, " + reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms roundtrip";
                                    `

Comment: I added a full section of code so you can see.  The code was working but then all textblock updates stopped across the board.  Tried even a simple test without requir=ing anything else and it would not update

Comment: @Shawn you're swallowing exceptions, maybe an exception is being thrown and you're not aware of it. try logging or rethrowing exceptions.

Comment: I just tried.  Removed anything that would catch an exception.  Nothing.  No explanation.  The textblocks are just not getting the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was updating the fields.  I had made an adjustment to the size of the grid which flattened all of the textblock fields to the left side.  Once I drug them out they were no longer auto-sized.

Thanks for the help!